# EnvironmentPermission Deny is obsolete in .Net 4.0 any alternate?

Tags: c#, security, unit-testing, .net-4.0, mstest

Hi I have a TestMethod in .Net 3.5 where I use EnvironmentPermission.Deny() to simulate a scenario to test the condition when access to the environment variables is denied.

Deny() has been made obsolete in .Net 4.0 and it gives compile time error.

How do I write a test for this scenario in .Net 4.0 ?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am in the same situation right now, especially since .NET 4.0 doesn't honor my PermissionSet properly, see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/693313/securitypermissionflag-skipverification-not-honored-in-net-4-0#details

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert on this, but I've tried to find some resources that might guide you.

According to the MSDN documentation, as you pointed out, `EnvironmentPermission.Deny()` is obsolete in .NET 4.0. The recommended approach is to set your assembly's permission set in order to control what your code can/cannot access.

Here's some links to help you (hopefully)

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.permissionset.aspx
- http://www.dotnetfunda.com/tutorials/videos/x86-what-is-cas-evidence-permission-set--code-groups-.aspx
- http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-code-access-security-in-.net-framework-4.0---part-i/

Comment: Hey Jas thanks for the pointers will definitely go through those and see what will be a good approach. Regarding changing the assembly permission set right now I have both the +ve & -ve test in the same assembly. Probably may need to split them out

Answer (score 2):

I think I have might just found a solution (although it still uses deprecated APIs):

Add the following to your app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Now you should be able to call `Permission.Deny()` without incurring a runtime exception.